# php_connect to odbc source produces TNS:could not resolve service name error after Xampp reinstall

Tags: php, oracle

I just updated my Windows Xampp install to get the latest PHP version and after the reinstall my web app is giving me the following error when trying to connect to an Oracle data source via the Microsoft ODBC driver for Oracle.

> Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC driver for
>   Oracle][Oracle]ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve service name, SQL
>   state 08001 in SQLConnect in C:\xampp\htdocs\webapp\connections\db.php
>   on line 34

The code I'm using for this is;

```
$dsn = 'dsnname';
$user = 'username';
$pass = 'password';
$conn = odbc_connect($dsn, $user, $pass, SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC);
```

This was working fine before I did the Xampp update and now suddenly it's not working. I think I had this problem once before but I'm convinced it was solved by adding the `SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC` cursor.

Anyone got any ideas on what could be wrong?

Comment: What happens if you test the underlying ODBC connection?

Comment: It works fine on it's own. I actually half solved this now. I found that if you don't start Apache as a service but start it manually the connection works fine. Not sure why this is but it's the workaround I'm using.